# What do the gutter colors linked to git changes in vs code mean?

Tags: visual-studio-code

in the following picture there are 2 colors created by git
[colors pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xex1p.png)
what does the two colors mean?
is there more and if there is what does they mean as well
And how can i remove them?

Comment: green is new versus the locked target, and blue means the current locked target is updated. For example, for a specific file, if you are updating an existed line, it will change to blue, and if you add new line, it will be green

Comment: Ok thanks. and how can i make it not appears when I'm changing/creating line of code

Answer (score 1):

Blue one is update to existing lines of code

Green one is new lines of code you have added

to get rid of it you simply need to stage your change and commit your code to git

```
git add .
git commit -m "my commit message here"
```

Edit:

to turn the gutter indicator off open up user settins in vs code by pressing the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>,</kbd> or if you are on a mac<kbd>Commnand</kbd> + <kbd>,</kbd>

go to `Features` > `Source Control`, look for `SCM: Diff Decoration`, and set it to `none`.

Comment: I mean how can i make it not appears when I'm changing/creating line of code?

Comment: Added an edit on how to turn this off in the answer